# Can I see two different frames on two different viewports of the same scene?

Tags: 3d-view

It is possible that I can see in two different viewports the same object, but on different frames?

E.g., I move a cube from frame 0 position 0/0/0 to frame 100 position 100/0/0.

So I would like to have two viewports open. 
First on frame 0 where my cube is on 0,0,0. 
Second on frame 50 where my cube is on 50,0,0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A frame number is associated with a scene (`bpy.data.scenes["Scene.rear"].frame_current`), and all view-ports are associated with the selected scene.

So you could possibly create another (temp edit) scene (Link All), use menu: Window :: New Main Window, and set the scenes differently in each main window.   You can then also set the current frame numbers differently, (0 and 50 in your example).

Any edits in one will appear in the other, as they will both react to changes in the in-memory elements.   The downside is all of the window switching you may labor through, but unlike me you may be blessed with a second monitor or sufficient screen space.

Comment: I guess you can either live in New York or afford a second monitor, but not both.